# Clarification in reaching components, Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I’m relatively new to using the javax.swing and java.awt so bear with me if I express my problem awkwardly.

Let’s say I have a custom made class CustomClass that extends and creates a JPanel **p**. In the class I add a JButton **b** to **p**. Later in another program file I create an instance of my CustomClass called **cp** and want to be able to catch for example a click event from **b** using the “actionPerformed” method. My question is how do I “reach” (like the written path to) the JButton **b** from instance **cp**? (Assuming that all relevant class files are already associated)

Comment: Don't extend panel. just use an instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use getters and setters if i understood correctly. I,e your `customPanel` will have a `public` `getButton()`  method which would return the `JButton` instance:

```
class CustomPanel extends JPanel {
    JButton button=new JButton("Some button");

    public JButton getMyButton() {
        return button;
    }
}

class Test {
    CustomPanel cp=new CustomPanel();


    void someMethod() {
       JButton b= cp.getMyButton();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

as per comment:

> what if I have like 10 or 20 different components in my JPanel, is
>   there some way to reach them without having to make a lot of methods

Simply call [`getComponentCount`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#getComponentCount%28%29) on `JPanel` instance and than iterate using a `for loop` and [`getComponentAt(int i)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#getComponentAt%28java.awt.Point%29) this will allow you to get access to all components on `JPanel`:

```
CustomPanel cp=...;//this class extends jpanel


for(int i=0;i<cp.getComponentCount();i++) {
    Component c=cp.getComponentAt(i);
     if( c instanceof JButton) {
         //do something
    }
 }
```

**UPDATE 2**

> What if I have two or more objects that should be of the same class
>   but otherwise treated as separate objects, how can I tell them apart
>   using the loop that you've provided me

look at `setName(String name)` and `getName` of `JButton` this will allow you to assign the instance a unique name which can be gotten by `getName()`. Alternatively use [`setActionCommand(String name)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setActionCommand%28java.lang.String%29) and [`getActionCommand()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#getActionCommand%28%29) to differentiate the buttons from another I prefer the latter.
Or you could even use their texts, via `getText()`

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This is a valid solution for the problem stated, but what I thought was that: what if I have like 10 or 20 different components in my JPanel, is there some way to reach them without having to make a lot of methods?

Comment: The button was just an example to have some component, there's no need to make a new class for it.

Comment: @user1967984 yes I see I read like my ***. Sorry. As per your previous comment see updated post

Comment: @David Kroukamp Thank you for your great help, but... :D the "instanceof" operator can only tell me if the component is an instance of the same class as the object I am seeking. What if I have two or more objects that should be of the same class but otherwise treated as separate objects, how can I tell them apart using the loop that you've provided me?